# Paho subscriber on_message -callback function moving into a seperate file

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

The classic- standard code is working perfect :

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("$SYS/#")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("mqtt.eclipse.org", 1883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

now, I want to move the on_message callback function into a new file, but this is not working? Not working means, MQTT messages are not recognized? The function "on_message" is not excecuted.
Any idea why?

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from new_file import on_message

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("$SYS/#")

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("mqtt.eclipse.org", 1883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

new_file :

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
```

Comment: You might want to show what's in the `new_file`

Comment: Also what errors do you get when you say "it doesn't work"

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory:

```
% python fails.py   
  File "fails.py", line 2
    import on_message from new_file
```

so if you change

import on_message from new_file

to

from new_file import on_message

it works.

Comment: Hi, no thats not the reason. The original code is longer, to post the problem, i changed and shortened the code. So it was my mistake to post the wrong code. The function is imported correctly, but it will not get executed when ever a new message is received. There is no error whatsoever.

Comment: You got the answer to your question. If the question is not right, then you will never get the answer.

Comment: So lets give it an other try!